# Change post sign in screen

Tags: 2013, office-365, redirect

So I have a public 365 SharePoint site, and when the "user" signs in it takes them back to the public default page.  Is there a way to change this to take the user straight to private content? I find it unnecessary and any one is able to sign in will not really care about what is on the public side.

I have tried messing around with the sign in link with no success.  I also thought I could have it load to a redirect page that took the user inside but apparently 2013 dosent have a redirect page OOTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was copying the link from the private sides home page and putting that in for the "sign in" link on the public site.  If the user was not signed in already 365 would prompt them for their user name/password, once entered they would be brought to the private page.

Not sure how it took me that long to think of this...

Comment: Super Jeff. Mark your answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the welcome page under site settings or you can go the page you want to make the welcome page and click "Make Homepage" in the ribbon.

Instructions:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/176/t/250937.aspx

Comment: I understand both the welcome page and the Make Home options.  However, I can not set a page that is on the private side of my SharePoint as the welcome page as it wont jump between sites.  And setting the private site as my homepage dosent do anything in regards to what page is loaded after a user signs into 365

Comment: You have the private data on a subsite?

Comment: no, the private data is not a subsite of the public facing site.  The private data is on a separate stand alone site

Comment: I just figured it out, thanks though!